# Error al realizar división de dos dígitos php

Tags: php

No entiendo que pasa con esto, quiero calcular una división y su resultado guardarlo en una variable, la linea es esta:

```
$total_paginas = $num_filas/$results_per_page;
```

El echo de esto me arroja esto: `0.33333333333333`

La verdad no entiendo, alli en la linea `$num_filas = 10` y `$results_per_page = 3`.

Esto deberia mostrar `3,3333333333333` y no lo hace.

He hecho esto `$total_paginas = ($num_filas/$results_per_page) * 10;` y si arroja el resultado bien, aunque debería mostrar el resultado bien sin necesidad de multiplicarlo por 10.

¿Alguien que me explique, por favor?

Comment: Revisa con un `var_dump` cual es el valor correcto de las variables `$num_filas` y `$results_per_page` para salir de dudas de que esta recibiendo esa división

Comment: Como he dicho esos valores son 10 y 3 respectivamente

Comment: Es posible que los valores que querés dividir sea un `string` y un `int`, por eso hace cualquier cuenta. Con el `var_dump()` te dice el tipo de dato que es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día sobre lo que informas la inconsistencia debe estar en las variables que enuncias, valida su contenido y prueba con el siguiente laboratorio para evaluar si te hace correctamente el calculo en tu server:

```
$num_filas = 10;

$results_per_page = 3;


$total_paginas = $num_filas/$results_per_page;

echo "<br> - total_paginas: ".$total_paginas;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Lo he hecho, $num_filas la lleno con $sql->rowCount() para guardar el numero de registros de una SQL, lo más extraño es que imprimo el rowCount y me muestra 10. No entiendo como es que cambia el valor luego

Comment: al hacer el laboratorio tal cual te lo menciono te brinda un valor diferente a "3,3333333333333" ?

Comment: Asi en plano si mostro el valor que es, aunque ya he conseguido el error, el cual estaba en mi consulta SQL, tenia SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tabla y lo he cambiado por SELECT * FROM tabla y ha funcionado como debe ser

Comment: en ese caso el erro estaba en las variables efectivamente, de igual forma es importante que valides si puedes hacer la consulta de otra forma ya que el * implica un desgaste considerable si es una consulta concurrente, trata de hacerlo enunciando un único ítem como "SELECT id FROM tabla" para evitar que te traigas todos los campos de la tbl. lo digo por performance. Saludos.

Comment: Asi es, solo lo habia puesto para probar. Ya le he colocado solo el id. Gracias Jose